# facebook iframe app problem.... opens on server not in facebook frame

Tags: facebook, iframe

I'm very new to facebook platform.

I developed an iframe app. which after allowing permsiions, opens the application on my server and not in facebook iframe.

I hope i'm clear. I'm using $user = $facebook->require_login().

I read somewhere that adding $facebook->require_frame() would help but it didn't help.

The page reloads with new access token on each reload.

Someoe please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some of the code you're using for the redirect?

If you use $facebook->GetLoginUrl to construct the Auth URL, the code should look like this -

```
 $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('canvas' => 1,
                                      'fbconnect' => 0,
                                      'req_perms' => 'permissions_here',
                                      'next' => $canvas_base_url . 'index.php',
                                      'cancel_url' => $canvas_base_url
                                     ));
```

In the Array, define your post authentication URL in 'next'. You should build it using the URL structure of http://apps.facebook.com/CANVASURL/yourpostauthpage.php.

In my snippet, I've created a variable ($canvas_base_url) to store my base URL.

Answer (score 0):

my code is

```
<?
$api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';

$secret  = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$appcallbackurl = 'http://www.phonecurry.com/fbapp/';

include_once 'facebook.php';



$facebook = new Facebook($api_key, $secret);


$user = $facebook->require_login();


try
{
if(!$facebook->api_client->users_isAppUser())
{
?>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
window.location = "http://www.facebook.com/login.php?v=1.0&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&next=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Fmycanvasapp%2F&canvas&req_perms=publish_stream";
</script>

<?php
}
}

catch (Exception $ex)
{
$facebook->set_user(null, null);
$facebook->redirect($appcallbackurl);
}

$has_permission = $facebook->api_client->users_hasAppPermission("publish_stream");
if(!$has_permission)
{
?>

<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
window.location = "http://www.facebook.com/login.php?v=1.0&api_key=xxxxxxx&next=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Fmycanvasapp%2F&canvas&req_perms=publish_stream";
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: You posted this as an answer to your question.  Take the source code you posted here and edit your question to include it.